# What does "Reply 'Done'" conventionally mean in Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

This is not so much of a programming question as it is about the convention.  What does `Reply 'Done'` conventionally mean as an alternative to just `Reply` to a comment on a code review in `Gerrit`?

Does it mean **I agree with you and will do it or have done it locally** or does it mean **I have amended the change per your suggestion**?  Because if I amend the change and push it into the same Gerrit review, the latest file revision on which the comments are made will overwrite the previous and all the comments from before will be gone (at least that's been my experience).

Answer (score 6):

The "Done" comment means that the comment has been addressed, typically by making the changes that the reviewer suggested. One normally publishes such comments after a new patch set has been pushed so that reviewers can have a new look and hopefully approve the change. Publishing the comments before the new patch set is actually available means that you'll be interrupting reviewers before there's anything new to look at.

Comments are never "gone". I don't know what you mean by that. It's perfectly okay to publish comments made on previous patch sets. Patch sets don't replace each other.

Comment: when i do git push of with the same change id, it pushes the new file and removes all the comments entered previously

Comment: This must be a misunderstanding. Gerrit simply doesn't behave that way. You will, however, have to look at the patch set where the comments were entered. They will not show up as comments in the most recent patch set.