# What does reply "Ack" mean in Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

This is not so much of a programming question as it is about the convention. What does **'Ack'** conventionally mean as an alternative to just reply to a comment on a code review in Gerrit?

Does it mean I agree with you but I am not going to change it and/or I have read and disagree with your suggestion?

I realize this is very similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618771/what-does-reply-done-conventionally-mean-in-gerrit) asked by amphibient but not quite the same as that has to do with **'Done'**:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Gerrit, replying to a review comment with "ACK" means "I agree with your comment". It's a little different from replying with "DONE" because the second one means "I agree with your comment and I've changed my code accordingly".

These pre-programmed short answers are used to "accelerate" the review process, but if you think they can cause some kind of confusion, it's better to avoid them and let a better answer to the comment.

Important: always answer EVERY comment.

Comment: I agree with this response and it is how our team uses ACK/DONE as well.

Answer (score -1):

It is short for ACKnowledged.
It came from network protocol terms syn/ack.

Comment: My question was with repect to Gerrit and not network protocol handshaking.

Comment: It is what gerrit uses to say „acknowledged“, I.E. they have accepted your input. It historically came from networking however it is used universally now to reply to any message or post you have „acknowledged“.